# How to use outer full join in laravel 5.0?

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, outer-join

It's my controller :

```
public function lihatpesanansemua() //ajax
{
    if(Request::ajax())
    {
        $hasil = DB::table('pesanan')->join('pemesan','pemesan.id', '=', 'pesanan.idpemesan')->join('komputer', 'komputer.id' ,'=', 'pesanan.idkomputer')
        ->select('pesanan.id', 'pemesan.nama', 'pesanan.tglpesan', 'pesanan.jampesan', 'pesanan.jamakhir', 'komputer.nama_komputer', 'komputer.lantai', 'komputer.Kelas')
        ->orderby('pesanan.id', 'asc')
        ->get();
        $hasil = json_encode($hasil);
        return $hasil;
    }
}
```

And that's is inner join. How to change to full outer join ? Thanks, sorry my bad english

Comment: _Which_ join do you want to change?  You currently appear to have _two_ inner joins in your query.

Comment: That's going to be a lot of code.  Are you sure you need full outer joins on _both_ queries?  Maybe you can share some data with us and what result you are trying to get?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what exactly your query is trying to achieve, and where you need a full outer join, but I will begin this answer by saying that MySQL has no inbuilt support for full outer join.  Based on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796872/full-outer-join-in-mysql), we can find a way an alternative way to write the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM t1
FULL OUTER JOIN t2
    ON t1.id = t2.id
```

This can be rewritten as a `UNION` of a left join and a right join:

```
SELECT * FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM t1
RIGHT JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
```

In Laravel, we can write the following code to represent the above full outer join:

```
$second = DB::table('t2')
             ->rightJoin('t1', 't1.id', '=', 't2.id')

$first = DB::table('t1')
            ->leftJoin('t2', 't1.id', '=', 't2.id')
            ->unionAll($first)
            ->get();
```

Again, I don't know why you think you need two outer joins, but regardless you should be able to adapt the above code and query and use it for your situation.

**References:**

- Link to full outer joins in MySQL: [Full Outer Join in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796872/full-outer-join-in-mysql)
- Link to Laravel 5.3 query builder docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/

Answer (score -1):

this code works for me to make a full join:

```
$second = DB::table('t1')
             ->rightJoin('t2', 't1.t2_id', '=', 't2.id')

$first = DB::table('t1')
            ->leftJoin('t2', 't1.t2_id', '=', 't2.id')
            ->union($first)
            ->get();
```