# Full outer join query in laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel

I have two table **application_requests** and **transactions** in both the tables there may be matching record or may not be. For any condition i want record from both the tables.

In **transactions** table there is a foreign key column **application_request_id** (this has value of reference of primary key in **application_requests** table).. If this condition matched then it should display as one row (or record).

I dont know how to achieve this in laravel.

I have tried below codes but its not working:

```
    $a = \DB::table('application_requests')->select('id');

    $b  = \DB::table('transactions')->select('application_request_id');

    $results = $b->union($a)->get();

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($results);die;
```

transactions table is
[image]

And my application_requests table is
[image]

Comment: You use join for this behavior, not union.
See https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#joins for an explanation.

Comment: It only give matched conditon records but i want all the records @marijnz0r

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use outer full join in laravel 5.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41662033/how-to-use-outer-full-join-in-laravel-5-0)

Answer (score 2):

just like that:

```
DB::table('transactions')->join('application_requests', 'transactions.application_request_id', '=', 'application_requests.id', 'full outer');
```

Answer (score 0):

Two outer joins to show all rows from both tables:

```
$second = DB::table('t2')
             ->rightJoin('t1', 't1.id', '=', 't2.id')

$first = DB::table('t1')
            ->leftJoin('t2', 't1.id', '=', 't2.id')
            ->unionAll($second)
            ->get();
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41662283/4587214

Answer (score 0):

```
    $results = DB::table('transactions')
                ->leftJoin('application_requests','transactions.application_request_id','=','application_requests.id')
                ->select('transactions.partner_id as tr_pratnerid','transactions.application_request_id as tr_applicationrequestid','transactions.class_2_1 as tr_clas21','transactions.class_2_2 as tr_clas22','transactions.class_2_3 as tr_clas23','transactions.class_3_1 as tr_clas31',
                 DO THIS TO ALL FIELDS FROM BOTH TABLE)
                ->get();
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($results);die;
```

Comment: Please include more context/explanation for this.

Answer (score 0):

this is the right code to make a full join:

```
$second = DB::table('t1')
             ->rightJoin('t2', 't1.t2_id', '=', 't2.id')

$first = DB::table('t1')
            ->leftJoin('t2', 't1.t2_id', '=', 't2.id')
            ->union($first)
            ->get();
```